# Issues pulling JSON values out in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, json.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in Visual Basic.
I am having trouble pulling values out of a JSON file. 
I can get the top most data, but nothing lower.
It tells me "Can not convert object to string.

Here is part of the JSON

```
{
    "WP0100300.htm":    {
        "alpha":{
            "title": "Alphabetical Index",
            "filename": "WP0100300-aindex.txt",
            "change": "None"
        },
        "T001": {
            "title": "Table 1. Summary",
            "filename": "WP0100300-table1.txt"
        }
    },
    "WP0100400.htm":    {
        "alpha":{
            "title": "Alphabetical Index",
            "filename": "WP0100400-aindex.txt",
            "change": "None"
        },
        "ref": {
            "title": "Reference Material Required",
            "filename": "WP0100400-refmatreq.txt",
            "change": "None"
        },
     }
}
```

Here is the portion of code that gets the values out of the JSON
The top most For Each works and I can pull back the name (WP0100300.thm) without a problem, so I assumed I would take the value for that name and parse it and run it through the same For Each to get the nested name (alpha) and then get its value so that I may get the title, filename, etc.  But I cannot even pull back the name of the first nested section of JSON.  The part where it says alpha, T001, etc.

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()

For Each item As JProperty In results
    item.CreateReader()

    Dim jResults2 As JObject = JObject.Parse(item.Value)
    Dim results2 As List(Of JToken) = jResults2.Children().ToList()

    For Each item2 As JProperty In results2
        item2.CreateReader()
        tvTest.Nodes.Add(item2.Name)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

`alpha`'s value is not a string. It's an object with `title`, `filename` and `change` properties.

If you're trying to add the name of each 2nd level object to your `TreeView`, the following will work:

```
Dim jResults = JObject.Parse(rawresp)

For Each item In jResults
    For Each item2 As JProperty In item.Value
        tvTest.Nodes.Add(item2.Name)
    Next
Next
```

This is much simpler than what you were doing. Hopefully it gets you set in the right direction. You don't need all the calls to `CreateReader` and `Children`.

Comment: I originaly tried item3.Value("title") and that didn't pull back anything but errors for me.  The code I ended up with just uses item3 and it pulls back "Alphabetical Index" which is what I need it to do , but other times I used item3.Value("title") and it pulled back what I needed.  If I use item3.ToString(), I get "title": "Alphabetical Index" if that helps explain what is going on at all.

Comment: My treeview should look like "WP0100300.htm" then its children will be  "Alphabetical Index" and "Table 1. Summary"  Then the tags need to be the value of filename

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I currently have working for me, I know it is not right, but it is working.
And I am happy to give other ideas a shot.

```
Dim reader = New StreamReader(jsonFile.ToString())
Dim rawresp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()

For Each item As JProperty In results
    item.CreateReader()
    tvTest.Nodes.Add(item.Name)

    Dim results2 As List(Of JToken) = item.Value.Children().ToList()
    Dim counter As Integer = tvTest.Nodes.Count() - 1
    tvTest.Nodes(counter).Tag = ""

    For Each item2 As JProperty In results2
        item2.CreateReader()

        Dim results3 As List(Of JToken) = item2.Value.Children().ToList()

       For Each item3 As JProperty In results3
           item3.CreateReader()

           If item3.ToString().IndexOf("title") <> -1 Then
               tvTest.Nodes(counter).Nodes.Add(item3)
           ElseIf item3.ToString().IndexOf("filename") <> -1 Then
               Dim counter2 = tvTest.Nodes(counter).Nodes.Count() - 1
               tvTest.Nodes(counter).Nodes(counter2).Tag = item3
           Else

           End If

        Next
    Next
Next
```

This sets my node as "WP0100300.htm" and the child nodes as "Alphabetical Index" and "Table 1. Summary" and then tags the child nodes with "WP0100300-aindex.txt" and "WP0100300-table1.txt"

I know it is not pretty , I had to do some string manipulation to achieve this which I am certain I did not need to and just did something wrong along the way.